# set of all reg exp vs set of all languages

Tags: elementary-set-theory, regular-language, regular-expressions

$\Sigma$ = {a,b,c,d,e}
V = {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H}

According to the notes:

The set of all regular expressions over $\Sigma$ is infinite and **countable**.

The set of all languages over $\Sigma$ is infinite and **uncountable**.

I don't get why reg exp is countable whereas language is uncountable.
I guess i can't seem to be grasping the subtle difference between them.
What's the difference?

Comment: The general idea is that regular languages are in some sense _regular_, while other languages might be chaotic. Similar situation happens with $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. You can characterize $\mathbb{Q}$ as the set of numbers which has finite or periodic binary expansion, i.e. in some sense regular. The binary expansion of elements of $\mathbb{R}$ might be infinite and aperiodic, i.e. in some sense chaotic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A language is just a set of strings.  A language $L$ over $\Sigma$ is a subset of $\Sigma^\ast$, which is the set of all strings made from letters in $\Sigma$.  $L$ contains some of the strings in $\Sigma^\ast$, but not necessarily all; it might contain, or not contain, *any* string of letters from $\Sigma$. $\Sigma^\ast$ itself is a countable set, and a countable set has an uncountable number of possible subsets, by [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem).  So the family of all possible languages over $\Sigma$ is uncountable.

However, a regular expression is an *expression* involving the operators $\cup,\cdot,\ast$ that *represents* a certain language.  For example, the regular expression $(\mathtt{0}^\ast\cup\mathtt{11^\ast01})\mathtt{01}$ represents the language $\{
\mathtt{01},
\mathtt{001},
\mathtt{0001},
\mathtt{00001},
\mathtt{10101},
\mathtt{000001},
\mathtt{110101},
\mathtt{0000001},
\mathtt{1110101},
\ldots
\}$.

The language that a regular expression represents is always a *regular* language.  And a fairly simple argument shows that the collection of all regular expressions over $\Sigma$ is countable: every regular expression is finite, so has some length $\ell$. Let $R_\ell$ be the set of regular expressions of length $\ell$.  Every set $R_\ell$ is finite.  (It has no more than $N^\ell$ elements, where $N$ is the size of $\Sigma$ plus the other symbols $\cup,\cdot,\ast, ), (,$ etc.)  The set of all regular expressions is just the union of all the $R_\ell$, and is therefore a countable union of finite sets and so countable.

(This provides one possible proof that there are languages that are not represented by regular expressions, and which are therefore not regular—indeed that *most* languages are not regular.  One simple example is the language of all strings of $\mathtt{x}$es that have length $p^2$ for some integer $p$.)

Comment: thanks your explanation was great. I have a small question regarding ur reg exp example. I tried to see if all ur reg exp examples were valid (since i have an exam soon and wanna digest as many examples as possible). how did u come up with ""? I couldn't figure it out. Thanks!

Comment: Take the $\mathtt{11^\ast01}$ part of $\mathtt{0}^\ast \cup \mathtt{11}^\ast\mathtt{01}$ and repeat the $\mathtt{1}^\ast$ part zero times, so that $\mathtt{11^\ast01}$ produces the string $\mathtt{101}$.  OK?

Comment: thanks!! got it. i thought 11* was equivalent to (11)*. instead its 1+1*. thanks!!

Comment: it's $\mathtt{1}\cdot\mathtt{1}^\ast$, not $\mathtt{1}+\mathtt{1}^\ast$.